# HTML/CSS/Javascript: iPad photo app like album punch in/out gesture

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, ipad

Is it possible to make a HTML version of iPad photo app like gesture(see the photos)? I made a [demo](http://rawgit.com/wilsonlmh/punchAlbum/master/). But I'm only able to make it triggered by click. I can't figure out how to make a consequent-gesture version. Would somebody give me tips ?
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your image/link to demo is not appearing is misformatted

Comment: @ZacWebb works now ;)